# I wonder how to solve the 'List' error of 'flutter'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   var questions = [
     {
       'questionText : what is your favorite color?'
       ,
       'answer': [
         {'Black'}, {'Red'}, {'Green'}, {'Blue'}, {'White'},
       ],       
     }];
```

Error : The literal can't be either a map or a set because it contains at least one literal map entry or a spread operator spreading a 'Map', and at least one element which is neither of these.

flutter ver 3

Mac M1

Comment: `{'Red'}` doesnt provide key and value pair , maybe you wanted to assign some value for color, or just wanted list of color, for last case remove `{` `}` from color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you actually want this?

```dart
   var questions = [
     {
       'questionText' : 'what is your favorite color?'
       ,
       'answer': [
         {'Black'}, {'Red'}, {'Green'}, {'Blue'}, {'White'},
       ],       
     }];
```

Now let's talk about the error:

```
Error : The literal can't be either a map or a set
because it contains at least one literal
map entry
or a
spread operator spreading a 'Map'
and at least
one element which is neither of these.
```

I suppose you are clear what are dart `set`s because you used it in your code. So I'll start with `map entry`.

A map entry is something like this

```dart
'key': 'value'
```

This is the usual way of creating `Map` indices.

`spread operator spreading a 'Map'` means this:

```dart
Map<String, String> a = {'a':'b'};
Map<String, String> b = {'c':'d', ...a}; // b = {'c':'d', 'a':'b'}
```

The spread operator is three dots followed by an `Iterable`. It extends the variable by that `Iterable`.

You used a map entry `'answer': [{'Black'}, {'Red'}, {'Green'}, {'Blue'}, {'White'},],`  and something else: `'questionText : what is your favorite color?'`

I personally believe this is a typo but I still want to make it clear.